# Laptop Displays on External Monitor by Default

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, laptop, display, hdmi

I was running Windows 98 through virtualbox (to play an old game that doesn't work on wine) and had to play with the resolutions a bit to get it to run at 800x600 (or less) on a monitor through HDMI.

The thing is, now every time I boot, the laptop display works just fine up until the point it loads the desktop, then it goes blank. The only way to get it to work again is plugging it into a monitor. Then after that I have to turn off the monitor so that it stays that when I unplug the HDMI. Needless to say, after two weeks I'm getting a bit tired of this work-around so was wondering if anyone knew how to get it to run on the native display by default so I don't have to do it every time.

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04 with Nvidia (with nvidia-prime).

Same problem may occur with Xubuntu.

Comment: This problem is still occurring. It also happens when I open up Steam or start a game, I have to plug the HDMI in and then unplug it. If anyone knows a way to revert resolutions and monitors to default settings, that will probably fix it but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to run `xrandr` then find the name of your default display. In my case it was LVDS-1-0.

Then to make it the default, I ran this command: `DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --output LVDS-1-0 --auto`

That solved everything for me, I can now use my laptop without having to  plug in a HDMI cable connected to a monitor anymore.